# How do I check if a string does not include the phrase, ";say " after the first instance of, ";say"?

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js

How would I check if a string doesn't include, ";say" after the person has already said, ";say" using discord.js.

I want to make sure the user doesn't break the bot that I am making by using the command ;say ;say ;say or something like that.

Solved, code and notes:

```js
client.on("message", msg => { // when user says something
    if (msg.content.toLowerCase().includes(";say ") && ((msg.author.id) !== ("690979386354302977"))) { // if it includes, ";say" and is not being sent by the bot
        msg.reply((msg.content).slice(5)) //say everything after the first 5 characters
    }
})
```

This bot is still pretty glitchy right now but I'll fix it sooner or later.

Comment: Look at `String.prototype.indexOf`. The second parameter is the index to start searching from.

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you try searching for finding number of occurrences of a string in a string, you might find what you are searching for...

Comment: you can also you `split` and check the length of the result

Comment: Or use *match* and check the result (dealing *null* if there are no matches).

Comment: @Artur I have been trying to use `((msg.content).slice(5)).includes(";say") === false` which is obviously not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

You want your bot to not break when you write something like `;say ;say ;say`, right? But why is your bot able to trigger its own commands anyway? The first line of most sane message handlers should be this:

```
if(msg.author.bot) return;
```

In other words, if the current message was sent by a bot, stop processing immediately and don't try to run commands. This way your bot and other bots can't trigger your bot's commands and you won't even have to answer this question in the first place.

Comment: I managed to fix it before I got an answer, but my code is really messy and looks bad oof.

Answer (score 3):

Plain JavaScript is pretty much enough to do the job in a nice and effortless manner.

You simply need to employ [`RegExp.prototype.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method that will *test* whether your input string contains pattern `;say` followed by some (or none) characters (`.*`) and then repeated again (`(\1)`):

```
!/(;say).*(\1)/.test(str)
```

Following is the quick demo:

```js
console.log(!/(;say).*(\1)/.test('')) // true
console.log(!/(;say).*(\1)/.test('When you ;say something ;say')) // false
console.log(!/(;say).*(\1)/.test('When you ;say ;hey')) // true
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Comment: You should probably clarify that you are using a regular expression, because the asker did not tag this question with regex, nor does he mention it in the question. You might also want to add an example in JavaScript.

Comment: I’d suggest you explain how that regular expression works, what that string of symbols means (yes, *I* know, but I’m willing to bet the OP - among many others - probably doesn’t).